# System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException: when trying to write to Excel Cell with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am trying to write my class property value to an Excel cell with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel but get the following error:
**System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException**

Here is my code:

...

```
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

...

```
//open excel file
Workbook wbAngebot = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(abs);  //abs = absolute path to file

//assign worksheet           
Worksheet wsAngebotsinfo = wbAngebot.Worksheets["Angebotsinformation"];

//write value to cell
wsAngebotsinfo.Cells[1,1] = AnredeVerk; //--> causes the exception, AnredeVerk is a string property
```

Is it possible that AskToUpdateLinks or ScreenUpdating or Visible xlapp-properties are causing the error when they are set to false?
I have also tried `wsAngebotsinfo.Range["A1"].Value` and `Value2` but same error occurs. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Which version of Excel and which version of the interop are you using?

Comment: Most current in Both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I set cell values using excel interop.

```
// Get the range object that represents the cell
//
var cell = (Range)worksheet.Cells[row, col];

// Set the cell value
//
cell.Value = value;

// Release the com object
//
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cell);
```

It is important to remember to release all objects you access.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it when i am back Home. I believe the exception Was caused because I did not Use a Release Object. Is it possible to Use oledb instead of Interop to write data to Ranges? And/or is there a more performant and less error prone Alternative?

Comment: I believe the actual problem is the assignment of string to the dynamic object instead of its Value property.  `wsAngebotsinfo.Cells[1,1]` is a dynamic object, and needs to be cast to `Range` in order to access the `Value` property.